# JBPM workflow will execute 24 hrs

Tags: workflow, jbpm

I recently working on JBPM workflow. I have requirements one workflow able to execute 24hrs without intervention in jbpm. ?

Is it possible ?

or I have to create scheduler based on the worklfow ?

Please guide me .. Thanks in Advance

Regards
Raj

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by being able to execute 24 hours without intervention? If your requirement is that a single process needs to be able to run around 24 hours then you will not have any problem achieving this with jBPM. There are some deployments of applications based on this workflow engine where it takes much longer to complete a single business process.

jBPM can be configured to use a database to store the process instance state. In that case it will save the state every time the workflow reaches a safe point. You can find more about this in [jBPM documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/release/6.4.0.Final/jbpm-docs/html/ch08.html). That is why it is not a problem to have long-running processes.